# How to Send http Request to Particular Sever address

Tags: c#, httpwebresponse

How to send Http Web request to Particular Server or IP Address?

Should I use Proxy server? Is there a way all the traffic can be send to specific server ?

```
    public static void SendRequesttoServer(List<string> DomainURLs)
    {

        foreach (var DomainUrl in DomainURLs)
        {
            try
            {
                var baseUri = DomainUrl.ToString();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(baseUri))
                {
                    HttpWebRequest re = null;

                    re = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(baseUri);
                    HttpWebResponse response = null;
                    try
                    {
                        response = (HttpWebResponse)re.GetResponse();

                    }
                    catch (WebException ex)
                    {
                        response = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Url: " + response.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri + " " + response.StatusCode);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You've got a list of URLs. Are you saying that you want to change the URLs so that all of the requests go to a particular domain? That would be the easiest. If the URL doesn't point to the server you want, change the URL. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Do you mean you have a DNS name that resolves to multiple IPs, and you want to connect to the same IP each time?

Comment: Thanks Scott, I have a list of URLs, I would like to send the HttpRequest to 1 Particular Server or IP address, Is there a way that all the traffic or request go to that  Server and get the response?

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes, Is there a easy to way to do that?

Answer (score -1):

Copy paste below full code and it will work...also check the grey comments section , it show how to set proxy

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var urlList = new List<string>();
            // add  destination REST Server or IP Address into list
            urlList.Add("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
            urlList.Add("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1");
            urlList.Add("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/");

            // Consume List items as paramter and prepare loop for processing
            SendRequesttoServer(urlList);

            // pause the console screen so it wont exit current console
            Console.ReadKey();

        }


        public static void SendRequesttoServer(List<string> DomainURLs)
        {
            string strResponseValue = string.Empty;

            foreach (var DomainUrl in DomainURLs)
            {

                    var baseUri = DomainUrl.ToString();

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(baseUri))
                    {

                        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(baseUri);
                        request.Method = "GET";   // DELETE\POST\GET...

                        // request.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;                          // set proxy , this method will use default windows client proxy value
                        // WebProxy proxyObject = new WebProxy("http://pproxyserverURL:80");    // this is another method whee allow you manual set proxy server value
                        // request.Proxy = proxyObject;                                         // this is another method whee allow you manual set proxy server value

                    try
                    {
                            using (HttpWebResponse resposne = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                            {

                                if (resposne.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                                { throw new ApplicationException("error code " + resposne.ToString()); }
                                else
                                {
                                    //process the response stream , can be JSON , XML , HTML...
                                    using (Stream responsestream = resposne.GetResponseStream())
                                    {
                                        if (responsestream != null)
                                        {
                                            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responsestream))
                                            {
                                                // REST return result was store here
                                                strResponseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                                            } // end of stream reader

                                        }
                                    } //End of using reponse stream

                                    Console.WriteLine("Url: " + resposne.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri + " " + resposne.StatusCode);

                                }

                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
                        }

                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```